# .NET Close Task with CancellationToken upon condition

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

How do you properly create a Task with a CancellationToken and close a Task upon a condition ?

For example:

```
CancellationToken CancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Run(() => {
  try{
    // Get some data from APIs...
    GetDataFromApi();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    // So here I want to cancel this task and I do not want any continuation Tasks to run
  }
}, CancellationToken.Token);
```

Do I need to check if the CancellationToken IsCanceled or how do I properly do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the way to set a task to `Canceled` state is to throw an `OperationCanceledException` and passing the cancellation token that was associated with the task (which is usually done by calling the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method). But this requires the token's `IsCancellationRequested` to be `true`. So one way to achieve the effect you wanted is to cancel first, then call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Run(() => {
    try
    {
        // Get some data from APIs...
        GetDataFromApi();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}, cts.Token);
```

Comment: I would recommend throwing an exception which happen inside of `try` block instead of throwing `OperationCanceledException` it will simplify the debug process and will be much cleary